# How to continuously count the number of times the column value=0 and restart when value>0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, database, count

I want to go from this:

```
df
     val1                           
0     0 
1     0
2     32
3     0
```

to this:

```
    df
     val1    count                  
0     0       1
1     0       2
2     32      0
3     0       1
```

How do I count how many times 0 comes in a row?

Answer (score 2):

- Make groups `df.val1.ne(0).cumsum()`, this makes a new group every time val1 isn't 0.
- Groupby those groups, and `cumsum()` where the number equals 0 in each group.

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(df.val1.ne(0).cumsum())['val1'].apply(lambda x: x.eq(0).cumsum())
print(df)

# Output:
   val1  count
0     0      1
1     0      2
2    32      0
3     0      1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby.cumcount` using the non-0 values to restart the groups, then `mask`:

```
m = df['val1'].ne(0)
df['count'] = df.groupby(m.cumsum()).cumcount().add(1).mask(m, 0)
```

Output:

```
   val1  count
0     0      1
1     0      2
2    32      0
3     0      2
```